# UISlider ignores starting value

Tags: swift, xcode, uikit

I have a weird behavior from my UISlider. I set it's initial Value and all looks fine in the Interface Builder. But it is ignored when a screen with it appears and my slider starts from a left position .  I tried to place a few breakpoints but I can't find anything about it in the debug area. Any advice how to fix or debug it?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a `IBOutlet` like you did for the label and name it `durationSlider`. Then set the initial values in the `viewDidLoad` function:

```
let duration: Float = 5

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    durationSlider.minimumValue = 0
    durationSlider.maximumValue = duration
    durationSlider.value = 3    // set your startValue here
    
    updateSliderLabel()
}

@IBAction func durationSliderChanged(_ sender: Any) {
    print("currentValue: \(durationSlider.value)")
    updateSliderLabel()
}

func updateSliderLabel() {
    durationLabel.text = String(round(durationSlider.value)) + "s"
}
```